# Moving an answer from a duplicate-question to the primary (but old) question?

Tags: discussion

I've composed [a long answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2272949/1714) to [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149561/diophantine-equation-7x-3y-2), but which appeared to me to be a duplicate only after posting my answer. The [primary question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007733/diophantine-7a2-3b) is quite old (2014) and has no answer so far. The newer question is of 2015. Is it better to (1) ***move*** that answer, to (2) ***cite*** it, or possibly to (3) ***mark the duplicity in reverse order***?

Comment: Is one of the questions of better quality than the other? Then that's the better place for answers. If there's no significant difference in quality, and only one has an answer, the one without answer should be closed as a duplicate of the answered one.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Hmm, the questions are essentially the same; only the primary question has some *"my approach"* ...